Replacing packed image with external image through Python
I have imported a game's level into Blender (3.3.21) and the importer packs the image textures. However, I have extracted these assets and would like to replace all the packed images with the extracted ones via python, but it does not seem to work... at least doing it in a simple way.
So far this is how I am doing things:
import bpy
import os

basedirs = "/media/edward/VERBATIM HD/GameExtracts/textures/JK.mat"

for mats in bpy.data.materials:
    if mats.use_nodes:
        imgname = mats.node_tree.nodes["Image Texture"].image.name[:-4] + " - "
        for paths, dirs, files in os.walk(basedirs):
            for filename in files:
                if imgname in filename and ".png" in filename:
                    print(paths + "/" + filename)
                    mats.node_tree.nodes["Image Texture"].image.filepath = paths + "/" + filename

Doing this I get the error
ERROR: Image "" not available. Keeping packed image

How would I go about just simply having the node use the external path rather than the internal package? I hope I don't have to go through the process of replacing the Whole node.

Ah, there was something I forgot. Instead of assigning the image.filepath this is how it should look:
mats.node_tree.nodes["Image Texture"].image = bpy.data.images.load(paths + "/" + filename)

